# Creating Two Lists from Equation

Tags: python

I have the function listed below where you can input an x-value and it will return a y value. I want to create a list of y-values that correspond to the mesh from 0 to 3 of 100 points that I created earlier.

```
nnode = 100
mesh = np.linspace(0,L,num=nnode)

def Analytical(x):
    var1 = 20 / (120*62000*3)
    var2 = -(x**5)
    var3 = 2*(3**2)*(1.5**3)
    var4 = (1.5**4)*3
    y = 1000*var1*(var2+var3-var4)
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy arrays are kind enough to let us do:

```
y = Analytical(mesh)
print(y.shape)
```

Output:

```
(100,)
```

There are your 100 values processed by the function.